# How to apply arithmetic operations on size of two queries

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count

I have two queries on the same table :

Query #1 - one with where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE condition1 ;
```

Returns *551 rows*

Query #2 - the other one, identical but with more conditions :

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3;
```

This returns *189 rows*

Result seeked :

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 
   AND (Q2_NumberOfRows / Q1_NumberOfRows > 0,15)
```

As you can see, in the 4th condition of Q2, I need to divide number of rows of Q1 by those of Q2. Because if this condition is not respected I don't want any row to be returned. I'm using the result as a filter by ID in another query.

So if (Q2_NumberOfRows / Q1_NumberOfRows > 0,15) then I assume that I have no ID to filter, otherwise I will.

How can I do that with only one query?

Comment: What result set do you want?  It is quite unclear.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Q1/Q2 row counts the right way round in your division? There will be the same or more Q1 rows than Q2, since Q2 has the more restrictive where clause. So `> 0.15` doesn't make sense?

Comment: Are the `condition1` in both queries different? If they are the same, then the query #1 will already contain whatever query #2 spits out.

Comment: @Gordon I've edited to add more clarity on what I want.
I also reversed Q1 and Q2 number of rows in last query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using conditional analytic `COUNT`s and then filtering the rows accordingly, like so:

```
SELECT <list of t1 cols>
FROM   (SELECT t1.*, -- ideally, you should specify the exact columns you want to retrieve.
               COUNT(*) OVER () cnt_all,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN condition2 AND condition3 THEN 1 END) OVER () cnt_restricted
        FROM   t1
        WHERE  condition1)
WHERE  condition2
AND    condition3
AND    cnt_restricted/cnt_all > 0.15;
```

The `OVER ()` part of the `COUNT` function is what makes it analytic - i.e. it won't collapse the rows. `OVER ()` means "take the whole data set as one group, with no ordering and apply the `COUNT` function to it."

This has the advantage over Zip's answer, in that you are only querying the table once.

Comment: I've never tried COUNT OVER() before but from what i've seen it and from what you said "it won't collapse the rows" but in your example there are neither group by or order by so what's the point ?

Comment: From your question, it looked like you didn't want the results to be aggregated. If that's not the case, you should edit your question to include some sample data and the expected output from that data. There isn't any group by (or order by, but if you wanted the results ordered, you could add that in yourself) in my query because I'm outputting the rows un-aggregated.

Comment: I don't need aggregate but I just wanted to understand if it's pertinent in your example (without aggregate) to use COUNT OVER()  :)

Comment: If you don't understand how analytic functions work, I highly suggest you research them. The `<function>() OVER ()` treats the whole result set as one unordered group, and outputs the result of the function against each row. That's what you want, right? For each row, you need to know the two counts, in order to work out the ratio.

Comment: (I mention order because if you include an order by in the analytic function, it turns the function into a cumulative function. E.g. `count(*) over (order by <some_col>)` would produce a cumulative count (treating rows with the same value as the same. E.g. rows with values in the ordered column of: `1`, `1`, `3`, `4` would produce counts of `2`, `2`, `3`, `4`). Cumulatively counting is not something you'd usually do and I'm struggling for a use-case that would require it. Other functions can require or make use of the `ORDER BY`, e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()` or `SUM()`)

Comment: I didn't understood at first that using OVER () would bypass SQL rule of using all fields in a group by when you're callign an aggregate function. I get it now, I tested your way and it does exactly what I want. Thank you very much

Comment: Analytic functions aren't the same as aggregate functions, so of course the rules of using them are different *{:-) I can't stress enough my recommendation to learn about analytic functions in more depth; they're extremely handy and they're not much more difficult (at least, without the window clause) to understand than aggregate queries. You'll find plenty of examples on here or via Google.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
WHERE condition1 
  AND condition2 
  AND condition3 
  AND ((SELECT count(*) FROM T1 WHERE condition1) / 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM T1 WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3) > 0,15)
```